# 2.3V minimum input voltage for 3.3V LDO

Tags: voltage-regulator

I was looking through 3.3V LDOs and I came across this

https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/low-dropout-voltage-regulators/9115697/

[image]

It's a 3.3V LDO yet the minimum input voltage is 2.3V. How can that be possible?

Comment: The tables/data in these distributer sites often contain errors.
What does the datasheet say ?

Comment: That regulator is probably part of a range or regulators with different fixed output voltages - some of them possibly as low as 1.5V and 1.8V.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to know something about a device, consult the [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20001826D.pdf) from the manufacturer.

> The minimum VIN must meet two conditions: \$V_{IN} \geq \$ 2.3V and \$V_{IN} \geq (V_R + 3.0%) + V_{DROPOUT}\$.

So, Vin must be larger in your case, about 3.3 * 1.03 + 178 mV = 3.577 V